# Detecting objects and finding the ratio of all the objects in the area in point cloud

Tags: object-detection, point-clouds, lidar

I have a problem with detecting objects in point clouds generated by Lidar. I want to detect objects and find the ratio of all those objects to the remaining of the point cloud. I just need advices to proceed. I found object detection studies but I have no idea what to do with finding the ratio of the objects to the remaining of the point cloud. Any advices would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. What software are you working with? What features are you detecting? What does the final product look like?

Comment: Hi, I use ROS to play bag file. I used depth clustering repo to find clusters but I need detecting objects and getting the occupancy of those objects like "these objects are 35% of this area". My main goal is to detect people but at first I want detect objects and get occupany ratio after that I will be developing for people occupancy. Thanks in advance.